# ADFS Error ID4037 on SAML Login: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037

Tags: active-directory, adfs, adfs4.0

I need to setup an ADFS RP trust between two adfs environments for SSO cross company and when setting up the RP / initiating a signon I am getting the below errors on the RP configuration on the SP side.  I've tried across multiple ADFS environments and get the same error so think has to do something with the SP ADFS / server 2022.

I have ADFS1 (IDP) which is server 2016
ADFS2 (SP) which is server 2022 (where I get the error)

Below is what i am seeing in the error logs in the SP.  Have added the certs in the root trust store on the SP side and not seeing cert validation errors.  Have validated the SAML asertion has the key info in it, using a SAMl post method for the login.

ERROR1

```
Cannot find certificate to validate message/token signature obtained from claims provider. 
Claims provider: http://<my hosst>/adfs/services/trust 

This request failed. 

User Action 
Check that Claim Provider Trust configuration is up to date.
```

ERROR 2

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenElement.ReadSecurityToken(XmlElement securityTokenXml, SecurityTokenHandlerCollection securityTokenHandlers)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.SamlMessageSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenElement.ReadSecurityToken(XmlElement securityTokenXml, SecurityTokenHandlerCollection securityTokenHandlers)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.SendSignInResponseForSecurityToken(GenericProtocolRequest originalRequest, SecurityTokenElement requestedTokenElement, ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Any help would be appreciated on this since cannot get this working.

Nick